# Doctrine YML schema to represent relationship from multiple columns

Tags: symfony1, doctrine, schema, yaml

I have table with following fields:

father_id
child_id

Both of them should point to table "sfGuardUser". I'm trying to define this relation in my schema files as following:

```
UsersHierarchy:
  tableName:                      users_hierarchy
  columns:
    father_id:                    {type: integer(9), primary: true}
    child_id:                     {type: integer(9), primary: true}
  relations:
    sfGuardUser:
      local:                      father_id
      foreign:                    id
    sfGuardUser:
      local:                      child_id
      foreign:                    id
```

But as a result only one of the columns become related to sfGuardUser table. So the question is how do I make both column point the same column in sfGuardUser table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because you have the same name for each relation. Try:

```
relations:
    sfGuardUserFather:
      class:                      sfGuardUser
      local:                      father_id
      foreign:                    id
    sfGuardUserChild:
      class:                      sfGuardUser
      local:                      child_id
      foreign:                    id
```

Then you can access your relations with:

```
$your_users_hierarchy_obj->sfGuardUserFather;
$your_users_hierarchy_obj->sfGuardUserChild;
```